# Canvas of webcam blinking during predictions (javascript)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, canvas, webcam, tensorflow.js

I draw my webcam stream on a canvas. I will apply my prediction rectangle bounding box on this canvas at each frame. Before starting prediction the canvas stream is prefect but as soon as predictions start the canvas starts to blink; I mean the whole canvas shows up and disappear, shows up and disappear very fast. do U have any idea how could I make it right? thanks a lot.

my prediction function looks like this:

```
let isPredicting = false;

async function predict() {
  ui.isPredicting();
  while (isPredicting) {
    // Capture the frame from the webcam.

    let video = document.getElementById('predwebcam');
    let width=224,
    height=224,
    frameRate=10;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: {
        width: width,
        height:height,
          frameRate:frameRate
        }
      }
    ).then(function(stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        video.play();
        video.addEventListener('play', function() {

        }, false);
      };
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('failed to load webcam')
    });

    var canvas = document.getElementById('predcanvas');
    canvas.width  = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    /*
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     */
    // video 'play' event listener
    video.addEventListener('play', function() {
      //context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      //draw(video, canvas, context, frameRate);
    }, false);

    function draw(video, canvas, context, frameRate) {
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      setTimeout(draw, 1/frameRate, video, canvas, context, frameRate);
    }
    //draw(video, canvas, context, frameRate);

    const img = await getImage();
    // Make a prediction through mobilenet, getting the internal activation of
    // the mobilenet model, i.e., "embeddings" of the input images.
    //const embeddings = truncatedMobileNet.predict(img);
    console.log('starting to predict')
    // Make a prediction through our newly-trained model using the embeddings
    // from mobilenet as input.
    const predictions = model.predict(img);
    const values = predictions.dataSync();
    const arr = Array.from(values);
    console.log(arr)
    let u = document.getElementById("1label").value;
    dict.add(classindex1, u);
    if (arr[0]>= 0){
      arr[0]=1;
    }
    var Id = arr[0];
    let ClassID = dict.findAt(Id);
    //console.log(ClassID)
    let startX = arr[1];
    let startY = arr[2];
    let w = arr[3];
    let h = arr[4];
    // Draw the bounding box.
    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    //context.shadowColor = '#d53';
    //context.shadowBlur = 20;
    context.lineJoin = 'bevel';
    context.lineWidth = 10;
    context.strokeStyle = '#38f';
    context.strokeRect(startX, startY, w, h);
    // Draw the label background.
    const font = "24px helvetica";
    context.font = font;
    context.textBaseline = "top";
    context.fillStyle = "#2fff00";
    const textWidth = context.measureText(ClassID).width;
    const textHeight = parseInt(font, 10);
    // draw top left rectangle
    context.fillRect(startX, startY, textWidth + 10, textHeight + 10);
    // draw bottom left rectangle
    //context.fillRect(startX, startY + h - textHeight, textWidth + 15, textHeight + 10);

    // Draw the text last to ensure it's on top.
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillText(ClassID, startX, startY);
    //context.fillText(prediction.score.toFixed(2), startX, startY + h - textHeight);
    // Returns the index with the maximum probability. This number corresponds
    // to the class the model thinks is the most probable given the input.
    //const predictedClass = predictions.as1D().argMax();
    //const classId = (await predictedClass.data())[0];
    img.dispose();


    //ui.predictClass(metaClasses[classId]);
    await tf.nextFrame();
  }
  ui.donePredicting();
}
```

Comment: There are a few things there that should be global, all your `document.getElementById` should be outside the loop, also the `canvas.getContext('2d')` in theory everything that remains the same should not be in the loop

Comment: Could you please make a working snippet demonstrating your error on stackblitz.com ? It will be easier to spot the error